# Not able to fetch Account details after overriding Standard new button on Contact?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura

I have overridden  Standard new button on Contact record that calls Aura and then calls LWC Navigation mixin event for record creation. Reason I wanted to override Standard new button was because I want to pre-populate some values before we create Contact record.

I am testing this functionality as Sales user who have only one record type access and for admins we have more than 1 record type access.

**Below is Code for Aura :**

**Aura cmp :**

```
    <aura:component
        implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasSObjectName,lightning:hasPageReference"
        access="global">
        <aura:attribute name="selectedRecordId" type="Id" />
        <aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" />
        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
        <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.reInit}" />
        <c:NavToNewContact recordTypeId="{!v.selectedRecordId}" objectName="{!v.sObjectName}" />

</aura:component>
```

**Aura Controller :**

```
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        //get record type Id
        let recordTypeId = component.get("v.pageReference").state.recordTypeId;
        component.set("v.selectedRecordId", recordTypeId);
    },
    reInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        console.log('reinit method:');
        var device = $A.get("$Browser.formFactor");
        if (device !== 'PHONE') {
            $A.get('e.force:closeQuickAction').fire();
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        }
    }
})
```

**Aura Rerenderer :**

```
({
    rerender: function (component, helper) {
        let device = $A.get("$Browser.formFactor");
        this.superRerender();
        let recordTypeId = component.get("v.pageReference").state.recordTypeId;
        component.set("v.selectedRecordId", recordTypeId);
        
    }
})
```

**Below is Code for LWC:**

```
import {
    LightningElement,
    wire,
    api
} from 'lwc';
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import {
    getRecord
} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import {
    getObjectInfo
} from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import USERCOUNTRY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Country';
import {
    NavigationMixin
} from 'lightning/navigation';
import FORM_FACTOR from '@salesforce/client/formFactor';
const FIELDS = [USERCOUNTRY_FIELD];
export default class NavToNewContact extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    userDefaultCountry;
    error;
    @api recordTypeId;
    recordPageUrl;
    
    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: USER_ID,
        fields: FIELDS,
    })
    userDetails({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            this.userDefaultCountry = data.fields.Country.value;
            if(this.recordTypeId !== undefined){
                this.navigateToNewContactCreate();
            }
            
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('error fetch default account country:' + error);
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

    // If User has access to only one record type then below wire method fetch default record type of logged in user.
    @wire(getObjectInfo, {
        objectApiName: 'Contact'
    })
    objectDetails({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            if (this.recordTypeId === undefined) {
                this.recordTypeId = data.defaultRecordTypeId;
                this.navigateToNewContactCreate();
            }
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('error while fetching record type is:' + error);
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
    navigateToNewContactCreate() {
        const defaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
            ShippingCountryCode: this.userDefaultCountry
        });
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: 'standard__objectPage',
                    attributes: {
                        objectApiName: 'Contact',
                        actionName: 'new'
                    },
                    state: {
                        //count: '1',
                        nooverride: '1',
                        //useRecordTypeCheck: '1',
                        defaultFieldValues: ContactDefaultValues
                        /*navigationLocation: 'LIST_VIEW',
                        backgroundContext: '/lightning/o/Contact/list?filterName=Recent',
                        recordTypeId: this.recordTypeId*/
                    }
                });
        
    }
}
```

Now if I goto Contact tab and create new Contact, I am able to create Contact records.
But if I create a Contact from Account related list of Contact then it does not pre-populate Account details. in Standard New Button, it does pre-populate Account details and also background URL is bit different When you create Contact from Contact tab and from Account.

Can someone please help me what is wrong in this code? How can I detect If New button is clicked from Contact tab(Where Account details should not be populated) or If button "NEw Contact" is clicked from Account(Account details should be pre-populated and background screen should same as Standard functionality).